Is it okay to use a single global http client for multiple requests?
I am working on a microservice that reads messages from a messaging queue and makes some http calls based on the information from the message. Specifically it gets proxyServerId and clientId from the message. proxyServerId is used to construct the proxyURL via which the request should go and clientId is the id of the client I wish to communicate with.
This clientId is also used to determine the X-Connect-Client-Id header.
serverHeaders.Headers["X-Connect-Client-Id"] = clientId

With current implementation I am creating a new http client everytime I want to make an http call to the client.


client := http.Client{
        Timeout: c.timeout,
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: c.tlsConfig,
            Proxy:           http.ProxyURL(c.serverURL),
            // Set proxy headers - to be consumed by Proxy server
            GetProxyConnectHeader: func(ctx context.Context, ProxyURL *url.URL, target string) (http.Header, error) {
                return c.setHeaders(ctx, c.serverHeaders)
            },
        },
    }

Now instead of creating a new http client for every request, I am planning to use a single global client that is created at the service startup but the proxyURL and the headers are dynamically passed when making the request via context
client := http.Client{
        Timeout: b.BuilderOptional.timeout,
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig,
            Proxy: func(request *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
                value := request.Context().Value(proxyURLCtxKey)
                // Check if proxy url is nil
                if value == nil {
                    return nil, errors.New("no Proxy URL found in context")
                }

                // Type assertion
                proxyURL, ok := value.(*url.URL)
                if !ok {
                    return nil, errors.New("invalid Proxy URL type")
                }

                // Check if url is empty
                if proxyURL.String() == "" {
                    return nil, errors.New("empty Proxy URL found")
                }

                b.logger.Debugf(ctx, "Proxy URL received from context: %s", proxyURL)
                return proxyURL, nil
            },
            // Set proxy headers - to be consumed by Proxy server
            GetProxyConnectHeader: func(ctx context.Context, ProxyURL *url.URL, target string) (http.Header, error) {
                b.logger.Debug(ctx, "Context from request", ctx.Value(headersCtxKey))
                return b.setHeaders(ctx)
            },
        },
    }

Is this approach (using global http client) valid ? Will there be race condition here since onle a single client object is being used and modified ? Or will golang internally handle concurrent goroutines using the same client object ?

” Clients should be reused instead of created as needed. Clients are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.”

The docs specifically say to reuse the client. Not only were you creating a new client for every request, but also creating and discarding a Transport, leaking the network connections.
